# How can you make a Data Bind attribute case insensitive?

Tags: javascript, data-binding

Code To make a specific row visible: data-bind="visible: email() == 'first.last@gmail.com'"

element/input ID is: email
Set Rule: first.last@gmail.com

When I type in first.last@gmail.com into the text field the new row will appear, however, when I type in First.Last@gmail.com it won't appear because the code is case sensitive **(as you can see, the F and the L are uppercase now)**. Is there anything that I can add to it to make it not be case insensitive?

[Example of the case sensitive email entered. Does not make the next row visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGpfy.png)

[Example of the email working when case is lowercase. Next row becomes visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Iydu.png)

Comment: Well, when you use ````equal value and equal type````  (````==````) and you explicitly type in a string (````'first.last@gmail.com'````), the boolean expression will only show true if the user input is exactly that specific string.  So in your one line of code, you are only accounting for one string input; everything else will be false.

What exactly are you trying not to allow?  Do you want the user to follow that exact format, no matter their given name and case sensitivity? Format, as in, keep the period between the first and last name?

Comment: @AttemptedMastery, I mean the F and the L are uppercase and the data-bind rule only accepts it when it is all lowercase to show the row. Is there anything I can add to the data-bind that will allow it to be case insensitive? I added pictures to show what I am referring to.

Comment: My question is, why is the data-bind making the user only use a certain case?  The user should be able to choose their case sensitivity.  Now, within your code, it is your job to make sure that all the usernames are uniform in their case sensitivity so you can easily work with them.  The convention is to use lower case them (````.toLowerCase()````), so that sensitivity isn't an issue.

Also, what I was trying to say is that you are literally only accepting this string:  "first.last@gmail.com'".  Out of all the millions of combinations, you are allowing for one username only.

Comment: Just think of it this way; with your current code, you only have ONE option to choose from and that is ````'first.last@gmail.com'````.  I am not sure what you are working on, but if you are trying to control inputs in a form, setting a strict string condition is probably not what you or the potential user would want...

Comment: @AttemptedMastery I appreciate your time to reply and  your input. My intention is to limit it to one email. There is a specific situation where a user's email needs to open up a new row. This databind is being added to hide that row until the email is entered. If you put their email in all lowercase, it works just fine, but if the person filling out the form uses capital letters, the data-bind fails. Does this make more sense? I apologize for the confusion I realize I am not doing a great job explaining my problem.

Comment: I am STILL really new, so I understand how hard it can be to communicate while learning.  Trust me, I do it all the time on here.

So hypothetically speaking, you are saying that if a username called 'first.last@gmail.com' has already been created and now, you want your user interface to create a new row when said user inputs his username.

You would never check for a specific string when you have a userbase... you need to do something that would work dynamically for all users.  Also, you would make it lower case in the expression to make sure you don't have to account for all cases

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
data-bind="visible: email() === 'first.last@gmail.com'.toLowerCase()
```

That way, you are validating the e-mail without any concern about the user's choice in sensitivity.  It could be this: `'fIrSt.lAsT@gMaIl.com'` but since your code makes it lower case, you are now only checking to see if the username actually exist and matches correctly to the `email()` function.

Now remember, there are a lot of blanks for me (and everyone else) in your question.

Also, in your `email()` function, you should make sure to pass the result in lowercase to like so:

```
function email(){
    return email.toLowerCase()
}
```

Now, when you go to check, everything will be uniformly cased and ready to go.

By the way, it would help if you posted more code :D